# When i picking server Date and Time then its giving me wrong time

Tags: codeigniter

Currently i am in India. In my Linux system, it's showing

> 2018-10-08     01:24 PM

But the below code is showing me the today data & time as

> 2018-10-08     03:50 PM .

Why time is not accurate? It's not working.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s A');


$arr = array("emp_id"=>$this->input->post('emp_id'),
             "gps_address"=>$this->input->post('gps_address'),
             "add_lat"=>$this->input->post('add_lat'),
             "add_long"=>$this->input->post('add_long'),
             "customer_id"=>$cus->customer_id,
             "emp_atten_status"=>"P",
             "emp_atten_color"=>"#228B22",
             "moth_year"=>date("M,Y",strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))),
             "login_status"=>"1",
             "signin_time"=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s A')
            );
```

Comment: What code below?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: i added code please check it.

Answer (score 1):

All of us knows that php is server side scripting. Normally date('Y-m-d H:i:s A'); gives a server date and time. To overcome and get the indian time we need to change the default time zone of the server by using syntax : **date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");**

Comment: <?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s A');  ?>

Comment: **For Linux You can use :**

`pecl install timezonedb`

and in php.ini put:

`extension=php_timezonedb.so`

Answer (score 0):

Add Below code in index.php

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
```

Comment: @MeghaThakur Try this code application/config.php at the top